# Get last price to see if profit or not. Print it in color

Tags: python

The Code is about the current price from the apple stock.
Now I want to show if they make profit or not.

Example:
current Price: 155.1

Price after that: 155.2

Now i want that it prints like that.

155.1 (First Price when program starts)

155.2 (Second Price) in green because profit to the previous price and if it drops like:

155.1 (Third Price) in red because there is no profit because previus value was 155.2

Hopefully you guys understood :D
My English is not that good

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://www.finanzen.net/realtimekurs/Apple')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'price'})[0].find('span').text
    return price


while True:
    print("Price:"+str(parsePrice()))
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to print text in color? How to compare two numbers?

Comment: Maybe im new to Coding.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with that, but what specific part of this are you having trouble with? SO works best with specific questions, rather than general "how do I make this work?" questions.

Comment: I dont know how i can compare the numbers and make it colourful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the colors by using the `colorama` lib. Also, I don't see where is your initial price, but nonetheless, switch your `while` statement for:

```
from colorama import init, Fore

init()

init_price = parsePrice()
while True():
    price = parsePrice()
    if (price == init_price):
        print(str(price))
    elif (price >= init_price):
        print(Fore.GREEN + str(price))
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + str(price))
```

This way you will need to save your initial price and compare in each iteration of the `while` loop

Note that you will need to `pip install colorama`

EDIT:

If you need to compare always with the previous value, just update `init_value` by the end of the loop:

```
init_price = parsePrice()
while True():
    ...
    init_price = price
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help! :)

Comment: But one Problem is there. If its Profit and its green but than its dropping than its also green. Maybe you can help me?